# How to encrypt a file in Windows using the current user credentials without EFS?

Tags: windows, encryption

I would like to encrypt a file using my domain account credentials and check it in into the source control. I would like to have the following functionality:

1. Anyone can check out the encrypted file.
2. The decryption procedure only asks for the password if the account attempting to decrypt the file is not mine. Alternatively, it never asks for a password and always uses the credentials of the account executing the command. if that account is not mine, then the decryption should fail.

I am wondering if there is anything out of the box doing what I need? If not, how would you implement such a scheme?

**EDIT**

Allow me to clarify. My password is not checked in into the source control. The decryption procedure should be able to use my credentials simply because I am logged in.

**Motivation**

The build servers needs to incorporate a certain API key into the build procedure. We do not want this API key to lay plain text in the version control. So, we have several options:

1. The API key is defined as an environment variable on the Build Servers. This is a configuration headache.
2. We encrypt the API key using the credentials of the Build account and check it in into the version control. The idea is that a build server checks the code out and is able to access the API key transparently.

We are not seeking a bullet proof routine, after all this is all inside the private network. So, if there is a limited group of users who know the build account credentials, then they will be able to decrypt the API key. But the majority of the developers do not have the build account access and will not be able to decrypt the API key.

I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. You should not be checking in your database password into source control.

Comment: I am not. What did I say to make you think I am?

Comment: Its the number 1 reason for people trying to "encrypt" a file in source control. Anyways, why are you trying to do what you are trying to do? Chances are you should be sidestepping the problem.

Comment: Hard code it into your build script? I know its dirty, but its the simplest method to solve all your problems. If you are worried about your devs having access to the build scripts, then you have other problems (namely they could hack out the API key anyway). But even so, are you sure the API key is in the build, or is it really a part of the deployment?

Comment: Normally you should cut your project in two. One part contains the code, the other credentials. The latter needs to be protected in order to keep others from seing it. Or you move the credentials to jndi or something similar and keep it outside source control completely.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you use the DPAPI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata

For example:

```
import win32crypt
blob = win32crypt.CryptProtectData(data, None, None, None, None, 0)
data = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(blob, None, None, None, 0)
```

This should work fine.